# Sort an array of hashes when some objects have nil attributes

Tags: ruby, sorting, hash

I have an Array of hashes where the keys are User objects (it's because I'm grouping search results by user like so: `#<User:0x007ffa3d570f00> => ["taco","pizza","unicorn"]`).

I want to be able to sort the array of hashes by the User object attributes like so:

```
search_results.sort_by{|item| item[0].age} #item[0] = User object
```

However, this throws a `ArgumentError: comparison of NilClass with Integer failed` when it encounters the first user where age is Nil. I tried adding a `unless user.age.nil?` in the **sort_by** block, but this didn't help.

Any ideas?

Comment: Wait.  If its an array of Hashes, then each element is a Hash, not a User.  Hashes don't have an #age method.  So I'm confused - what are you trying o accomplish?  Which of the keys of each Hash do you want the #age of?

Comment: @MarkReed Hmmm, good point, though the error seems to imply that it is getting the `age` (since it's an integer), and otherwise it'd be failing with `NoMethodError` trying to call `age`.

Comment: Which tells me maybe your search_results isn't what you think it is. Did you try just pp'ing it?  Or asking for search_results[0].class?

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain myself well enough, it's an array of hashes where the key is a 'User' object and the value is an array. Hence the "sort_by" method. This is a common pattern

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Treat the `nil` objects as something else, perhaps `0` or `Float::INFINITY`?

```
search_results.sort_by { |user| user.age || 0 }
```

Since `nil.to_i == 0`, you could also do:

```
search_results.sort_by { |user| user.age.to_i }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
search_results.sort_by{|user| user.age ? user.age : 0 }
```

Answer (score 0):

For boolean values, based on megas' solution:

```
[true, false, false, true].sort { |a|
         a ? 0 : 1
      }

=> [true, true, false, false]
```